# How can I lock the keyboard and mouse when playing video

Tags: video, lock-screen, kiosk

I'd like to set up my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop so that I can play a video on loop while my computer is unattended, while not allowing anyone to take over without a password. I think this could go one of two ways, but both seem unneccesarily difficult or hacky:

1. Find a video player that can lock the keyboard and mouse with a password, or
2. Use the normal ubuntu lockdown with a screensaver that plays a video on loop.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble finding an easy way to do (1) and it looks like Ubuntu doesn't even have screensavers any more, so (2) is difficult as well.

Any suggestions about the best way to do this would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [**xtrlock**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xtrlock.1x.html),

> xtrlock locks the X server till the user enters their password  at 
>   the
>          keyboard.
>
> ```
>    While  xtrlock  is  running, the mouse and keyboard are grabbed and the
>    mouse cursor becomes a padlock.  Output displayed by  X  programs,  and
>    windows  put  up  by new X clients, continue to be visible, and any new
>    output is displayed normally.
>
>    The mouse and keyboard are returned when the user types their password,
>    followed  by Enter or Newline.  If an incorrect password is entered the
>    bell is sounded.  Pressing Backspace or Delete erases one character  of
>    a  password  partially  typed; pressing Escape or Clear clears anything
>    that has been entered.
>
>    If too many attempts are made in too short a  time  further  keystrokes
>    generate bells and are otherwise ignored until a timeout has expired.
>
>    The  X  server  screen saver continues to operate normally; if it comes
>    into operation the display may  be  restored  by  the  usual  means  of
>    touching a key (Shift, for example) or the mouse.
> ```

install it using

`sudo apt-get install xtrlock`

Open terminal run `xtrlock` to lock the Keyboard and mouse inputs .

Caution , **Enter your Active user Password to unlock it and press enter.**